# Remove Dependency of attributes in configurable product

Tags: magento, attributes, configurable-product

How can i remove dependency from attributes of configurable products in magento. 
i want customers to select those attributes in any order. 
Can anybody please tell me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the order of the `Super product attributes configuration` blocks on the tab `associated products` of your configurable product in Magento backend.

Here you can change the order which the customer has to select, but unfortunately, the options can't be select in any order as you would like to do.

Comment: Thank You Gerard for ur help. Is it possible by changing any file or changing code? is there any extension for this? i'm really having a lot of trouble due to this problem....

Comment: It's not possible by changing just one file. You have to rewrite the Magento logic for configurables and I expect that's not what you want. Maybe you can use custom options instead? Also check out the answer on this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11463/configurable-attribute-selection-dependency-in-product-view-page

Comment: Thanks Gerard de Visser for ur response but the problem is that i'm not only using attributes i have implemented logic, while selecting three attributes it loads simple product with its custom options, the problem is while i change 1st attributes it changes 2nd and 3rd attribute to choose Option.. I just want that while i change 1st attribute value 2nd and 3rd attributes value selection should not be changed. Please take a llok at bellow link, project.apeiront.com/crownmoulding/index.php/faux-beam/tuscany-beam.html